# mysql, key and optimization: does my key seem to be useless?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Here are the sql commands I've done, and I don't understand why there's so few difference between without the key (~1.45 s), and with the key (~1.15 s):

```
mysql> show create table devis;
| devis | CREATE TABLE `devis` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ...blabla...
  `date_v_creation` datetime default NULL,
  `date_v_fin` datetime default NULL,
  ...blabla...
  `etat` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  `etat_date` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `date_v_creation` (`date_v_creation`),
  KEY `date_v_fin` (`date_v_fin`),
  ...blabla...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3714317 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

mysql> select date_v_creation from devis
where etat=3
and date_v_fin is null
and TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(date_v_creation) > 54;

+---------------------+
| date_v_creation     |
+---------------------+
| 2011-10-30 21:44:54 | 
| ...blabla...        | 
| 2011-10-30 21:48:05 | 
+---------------------+
216 rows in set (1.45 sec)

mysql> alter table devis add key( date_v_fin, etat);

mysql> select date_v_creation from devis
where etat=3
and date_v_fin is null
and TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(date_v_creation) > 54;

+---------------------+
| date_v_creation     |
+---------------------+
| 2011-10-30 21:44:54 | 
| ...blabla...        | 
| 2011-10-30 21:48:05 | 
+---------------------+
216 rows in set (1.13 sec)
```

If I do it a lot of times, it's always between (1.05 sec) and (1.15 sec).

There have been a lot of times where I've added keys to have a shorter response time, and when it didn't work, the time didn't change, and *when it worked, the time change to a factor of 10 to the least*.

Am I doing something wrong, missing something or is this normal t gain so few?

Thanks a lot!

### Update

Here's the query that solved my problem but I still don't get why it solved it.

```
select date_v_creation
from devis
where etat=3
  and date_v_creation < NOW() - INTERVAL 54 DAY
  and date_v_fin is null;
```

Here's the explain of my "bad" query:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select date_v_creation from devis where etat=3 and date_v_fin is null and TO_DAYS(NOW()) - TO_DAYS(date_v_creation) > 54;
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys           | key        | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | devis | ref  | date_v_fin,date_v_fin_2 | date_v_fin | 9       | const | 15913 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.34 sec)
```

Here's the explain of the "good", optimized query:

```
mysql> explain select date_v_creation from devis where etat=3   and date_v_creation < NOW() - INTERVAL 54 DAY   and date_v_fin is null;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                           | key             | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | devis | range | date_v_fin,date_v_creation,date_v_fin_2 | date_v_creation | 9       | NULL | 1458 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: use EXPLAIN SELECT ... , that tells you if it's using any indexes, among other things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically two problems:

1. There is no useful key for the query: useful here is the key that includes index on the field with equation, and then with the comparison. That is you need a key on (etat, date_v_creation)
2. the index on `date_v_creation` currently can not be used, because the comparison is on a function of the field value instead of the value itself. That's why the key on `date_v_creation` did not help. SO you should rewrite the query as follows:

   ```
   select date_v_creation
   from devis
   where etat=3
     and date_v_creation < NOW() - INTERVAL 54 DAY
     and date_v_fin is null;
   ```

Comment: You're right, you're the one! Damn thas was impressive! **`1089 rows in set (0.15 sec)`.** But re-read my question: I still don't get why your solution works: my request is about `etat` and `date_v_fin` => `where etat=3 and date_v_fin is null` that's why I've made an index on these two fields: `alter table devis add key( date_v_fin, etat);`. So how comes it wasn't optimized?

Comment: @olivier-pons, I shortly formulated why it was not optimized. But you can read the article to get some more details: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/ =)

Comment: The problem seems not to come from the index, but from the `TO_DAYS()` which seems to be calculated for each row, whereas your solution use pre-caculated stuff. There's no need to re-calculate `date_v_creation` here: **`date_v_creation < (NOW() - INTERVAL 54 DAY);`**. I'm re-read what you said, and now I get it. Sorry, my english is still not good whereas I'm working on it every day ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Olivier, here are the general thoughts. It would be better if your post the plans.

1. B-Tree index in MySQL doesn't store null. So, if you want to filter out smth by `column is null` you should following the following strategy (if you really need it). Add another column `is_null tinyint`. Set it to 1 or 0. Create index on it.
2. Concerning `etat`. What is the selectivity (= distinct rows/all rows) value for this column? If it is low creating B-Tree index will not affect performance to high. The ideal selectivity is 1 but such a selectivity can be reached only by unique indexes on `NOT NULL` columns.

Comment: etat is either 1,2 or 3. on more than 40 000 rows

Answer (score 0):

`date_v_creation` is not included in your index, so MySQL still has to scan rows in the table to do the SELECT. That's my guess, anyway--`EXPLAIN SELECT...` will tell you the details of what the query planner is doing.

[Null column values *are* indexed with MySQL b-trees.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)